# Continuity of functions which are not continuous

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$f(x)$ is a discontinuous function defined as 1 everywhere except at $x=4$ where it is defined as $-1$.

$g(x)$ is a discotinuous function defined as $4x-10$ everwhere except at $x=4$ where it is defined as $-6$.

Question 1:  is $f(x)g(x)$ continuous?  I think my issue is that I don't know the rules for multiplying piecewise functions.

Question 2: is $g(x)-6f(x)$ continuous.  My issue again is how to do basic arithmetic operations on piecewise functions.

Comment: Rules for multiplying piecewise functions? Nothing is different, e.g. $(fg)(x)$ at $1$ is $f(1)g(1)$, "plug in the values of $f$ and $g$ and multiply these numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both your functions, f(x)g(x) and g(x)-6f(x) are continuous.

The only potential problem point is $x=4$ and these functions are continuous at $x=4$ due to the value being equal to the limit.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I now see that was the entire point to the continuity section.

Comment: @user163862 Thanks for your attention and understanding.